# USAN filter in OpenCV - custom filter

Tags: opencv, filtering

I'm trying to implement SUSAN corner detector in OpenCV [Details here](http://users.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/~steve/susan/susan/node10.html).

So far I have the filtering function, but there is a problem, that this is not an linear operation. According to documentation it's possible to use *FilterEngine* and *BaseFilter* to write custom filters. There are unfortunately no detail how to implement the filtering function **dst(x,y) = F(src x kernel)**. I'm using C++ and OpenCV 2.3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a couple of lines, on how you plan to implement it? In my opinion, the USAN is easier to implement as an integral (sum over pixels) than as a convolution (2Dfilter).

Answer (score 1):

A nice tutorial how to implement custom 2D filter based on kernel convolution is [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html)!